# how to pass md5 checksum as a parameter using transfer.upload_file()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, s3transfermanager

I want to pass the precalculated md5 checksum of a file as a parameter[Boto3], so that s3 checks against its own calculated md5/etag and discards if the md5 doesn't match. (I do know that in multipart etag is not md5). 
Is there a way to do it with(s3transfer) transfer.upload_file()?
Or any other way to do that? Please point me in right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Have you reviewed the source code? I would hope that `upload_file()` does this for you automatically while it's uploading the file.  When doing a multipart upload, a `Content-MD5` is sent in the request with each part, and it's the md5 of each part that is sent for S3 to use when doing the comparison and deciding whether to accept or reject each part (at the part level; parts can thus be retried).  The final object etag is the hex md5 of the concatenated binary md5 of each uploaded part (then `-` plus the number of parts).  There is no raw md5 for the entire object that S3 considers.

Comment: Umm, suppose i'm sending a small file, (because i don't know it beforehand what the sizes are gonna be)..... shouldn't there be some way to confirm that the md5 that is calculated by boto is the same as the e-tag?. I want to precalculate the md5 on my own... and then verify it against the e-tag that is calculated by s3. 
But where/when is Boto calculating the md5, i can't seem to quite understand. 
I wanted to see what md5 Boto is calculating. (let's forget the multipart for the time being); Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only store the md5 into metadata and use it as verification as describe [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/), to use md5 as verification , it is only possible using [put_object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)

[s3 tranfer](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html)  allow you to save the metadata but without verification ability .

```
transfer.upload_file('/tmp/myfile', 'bucket', 'key',
                     extra_args={'Metadata': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}})
```

Comment: Makes sense, but put_object doesn't handle multi-part uploads, which is why i needed s3Transfer. And, s3Transfer doesn't really help in checking file integrity...which was also a requirement for me. Sounds like i will have to [1] pass it (md5) as a meta-data [2]and then fetch the e-tag and metadata [3] compare them [4] if they don't match _then_ Delete the object.

Comment: @RishavSrestha : i think there is similar requirement done by other. To verify proper multipart upload, data verification checksum is always in place. Perhaps you need use the api that change the S3 object metadata.